# Sending and reading string to/from PrintWriter and BufferedReader

Tags: java

I have a server client that sends and receives info from the server socket using a PrintWriter for outgoing messages and a BufferedReader for incoming messages. I'm trying to test the client without a server connection in JUnit by sending strings to the client through the BufferedReader and reading the returned output from the PrintWriter.

```
class Client{

    private BufferedReader incomingMessage;
    private PrintWriter outgoingMessage;
    private StringWriter output;

    //Constructor for testing without server connection
    public Client(){
       output = new StringWriter();
       outgoingMessage = new PrintWriter(output);
       incomingMessage = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    }

     //Methods for processing incoming messages and sending responses are
     //omitted
     //responses are sent using outgoingMessage.println("msg");


     public void sendStringToInputStream(String msg){
         incomingMessage = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(msg));
     }

     public String getOutputAsString(){
         return output.toString();
     }
}
```

This is the test I'm running.

```
public class ServerMessageTest {

    private Client testClient;
    private String output;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        testClient = new Client();

    }

    @Test
    public void testClientOutputMessage(){
        testClient.sendStringToInputStream("GAME A OVER SEND OUTCOME");
        output = testClient.getOutputAsString();
        String testString = "GAME A OVER PLAYER 1 0 PLAYER 2 0";
        Assert.assertEquals(testString, output.toString());
    }
}
```

The test fails showing this:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :GAME A OVER PLAYER 1 0 PLAYER 2 0
Actual   :
```

So there's an issue with reading the output message or setting the input message. I'm kinda new to IO stuff, so if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your variable names are bizarre. A `BufferedReader` isn't a message, and neither is a `PrintWriter`.
2. You aren't doing any output or input in this code. You need to call `println()` to send the message, and `readLine()` to receive it. Converting the reader and writer to strings accomplishes exactly nothing.
3. You need to create your reader and writer *once* per *socket*, not once per message.

Comment: This is actually not my code. Part of my assignment is to extend and test the functionality of a classmate's code. I'm trying to understand what they're doing here, but I can't. There are methods in the actual code that print and read lines through the BufferedReader and PrintWriter. I can't post those because we aren't allowed to. I just need to figure out how to capture the output stream from the PrintWriter, and force input through the BufferedReader without connection to a socket. I understand they're input/output streams. Just need help accessing them.

Comment: It isn't even slightly relevant whose code it is. The code you posted has the flaws I mentioned. If this isn't the real code, or all the relevant code, or the actual question you're asking about isn't completely contained within your question, it is a complete waste of time.